# bookshelf.js relationship hasMany error

Tags: javascript, node.js, relationship, bookshelf.js

I'm getting the following error on a `hasMany` call using Bookshelf:

```
 A valid target model must be defined for the roles hasMany relation
```

Role.js

```
var Data = require('../server-includes/Data'),
    User = require('./User');

var Role = Data.bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'roles',
  users: function() {
    return this.hasMany(User, 'role_id');
  }
});

module.exports = Role;
```

User.js

```
var Data = require('../server-includes/Data'),
    Role = require('./Role');

var User = Data.bookshelf.Model.extend({ 
  tableName: 'users',
  role: function() {
    return this.belongsTo(Role, 'id');
  },
};

module.exports = User;
```

Usage:

```
new Role({ id: req.params.id })
.fetch({ require: true, withRelated:['users'] })
.then(function (role) {
  role.users().fetch().then(function(users) {
    console.log('users: ' + users);
  });
})
```

Answer (score 9):

I reference my models as strings, and use Bookshelf's [registry plugin](https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/wiki/Plugin:-Model-Registry).

```
var bookshelf = new Bookshelf( knex );
bookshelf.plugin( 'registry' );
```

Then I define and create a model:

```
var userModel = /*do bookshelf things*/;
bookshelf.model( 'User', userModel );
```

Then when I create a `.hasMany`, I use a string to reference.

```
users: function() {
  return this.hasMany( 'User', 'roleId' );
},
```

Answer (score 2):

post.js

```
Bookshelf.plugin('registry')
var Category = require('./category')
var Post = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'posts',
    hasTimestamps: true,
    categories: function () {
        return this.belongsTo('Category', 'category_id');
    },
});
module.exports = Bookshelf.model('Post',Post);
```

category.js

```
Bookshelf.plugin('registry');
var Post = require('./post');
var Category = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'categories',
    hasTimestamps: true,
    posts : function () {
         return this.hasMany('Post');
    }
});
module.exports = Bookshelf.model('Category', Category);
```